# Android MVP: is it just an excuse to enable testing?

Tags: android, mvp

I honestly cannot get my head around all this MVP and similar stuff with respect to Android: What is its real point?

Up until now the only practical reason I see to use MVP in Android is to 'extract' unit-testable pieces of code from framework classes (i.e. Activities, Services, Fragments...) which would otherwise be difficult (or impossible) to test.

This is nice but this way Activities (and other framework classes) end up  delegating work to the presenter when possible (i.e. when dealing with framework agnostic code) and doing work directly when not. Because of this Presenters end up looking somehow bizarre by having methods which mirror the Activity lifecycle ones (onStart, onResume, clickListeners...). I wonder if this is a code smell?

On top of this I see a ton of libraries/patterns to build MVP Android apps but I honestly don't see their real benefit: what is the downside of having each Activity creating and managing its own presenter manually?
I see no benefit in decoupling the Activity and the Presenter from each other, since the presenter is merely the 'extraction' of some code from the Activity it will be tightly coupled to it by definition and this sounds to me fine as long as the presenter contains only strictly presentation logic (the rest of the business logic shall go into dedicated classes which don't know anything about the View/Presenter duo).

I'm feeling a bit lost in this topic and I'd like some other opinions on the matter to gain a greater perspective.

Comment: If something is easy to test - it is also easy to read, maintain, re-use... list goes on. So, testing is just a extra benefit you get from writing a good code.

Comment: Testing is just another virtue of the MVP pattern. Having a separated Presenter clearly decouples the interaction between _how the application interacts with the rest of the world_ (whatever storage, whatever communication, etc) and _how the application interacts with the user_ (display an activity, show a message to a log, or just simply beep).

Comment: Duplicating Activity lifecycle methods in a Presenter is probably not the best way to use the pattern, Presenter should be able to work with any View, not necessarily an Android Activity. Imagine View being a console, will it make sense for it to call `onStart()` on the Presenter?

Comment: @Egor so let's say I need to start some of my business logic when the Activity becomes visible. I don't want my view (activity) to depend on my business logic, I want my presenter to.
How can I do this if not by 'forwarding' the onStart() call to the presenter and let the presenter start the business logic?

Comment: What exactly would "start the business logic" mean in a specific use case? If it's, say, loading a list of cat pictures, then call your method `loadCatPictures()` - the presenter doesn't need to know that you're calling it in your Activity's `onStart()`.

Comment: Ok. Let's say that during onStart() besides loading the cat pictures I also have to change some global state of the app: let's say I have to enable Blutooth LE scanning when the Activity is visible.
Following your example the activity should have in it's onStart() {presenter.loadCatPictures(); presenter.startScanning()} but: is this something which the view should be aware of? It is not purely presentation, I don't see why the activity should bother with bluetooth stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure, you can make you presentation logic framework-agnostic for testing, but MVP also helps to change the behaviour at runtime by changing presenters. View interface should have bit more abstract methods (not 'hide button X', describing , say, displaying a set of data). By decoupling the UI logic from the framework-dependent implementation, we can use different Views for changing UI, or Presenter for changing logic at runtime. View - Presenter is also a 'shim', which makes it harder to write 'spaghetti' code

Answer (score 0):

From long term perspective your code should be feasible and easily maintainable, No one want to spend extra time to refactor code.No, when we starting our project we should thing about proper patterns to do.

Talking about MVP it provides you the presenter layer which can be easily testable and there is no view reference so you can easily perform junit test cases otherwise you have to use other UI test cases.

you can reuse same presenter anywhere you want as it contains only business logic

so, my suggestion you should go ahead with MVP if you don't wanna face future code problem

Comment: In an android app context I really can't see the benefit of using the same presenter with two different Activities.

The presenter should contain the framework agnostic code that is strictly related to presentation (i.e. handling input events, react with output events ) , all other kind of reusable code (i.e. business models,  network layer, databases...) should not be  implemented in the presenter but should be used by the presenters.

Comment: `when we starting our project we should thing about proper patterns to do` - you should think how to make a good app and follow SOLID principles, not pick patterns.

Comment: you mean we don't have to focus on design pattern. seriously ?

Comment: @jiteshmohite You just don't have to focus on patterns as the primary target. Your code should follow SOLID as the primary target since it can cover the overall application design, and use respective patterns, as the secondary target, in more concrete situations where they are really justified (applicable for the design patterns, the architectural patterns, etc) -- if they really are for a particular case.